# Ember Views and initializing with values - TypeError: this.currentState is undefined

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, frontend

I am having trouble working with ember views and initializing them with values before the template is rendered. With my code below, I am getting the following error in the browser:

> **TypeError**: this.currentState is undefined
>   this.currentState.childViewsDidChange(this, views, start, added);

My question is, what does the error message mean, and is there another approach that will work better?

```
App.SmileyFaceView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  childViews: null

  init: () ->
    @_super

    happy = App.SmileyFace.create()
    happy.setFace(":)")

    angry = App.AngryFace.create()
    angry.setFace(">:(")

    blah = App.BlahFace.create()
    blah.setFace(":|")

    @pushObject(happy)
    @pushObject(angry)
    @pushObject(blah)

App.SmileyFaceView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: "span"
  template: null

  setFace: (face) ->
    @set('template', Ember.Handlebars.compile(face))
```

Comment: You might want to give your different views different names. (Also, define the childview first. Don't know if it's required, just makes more sense...)

Comment: have you tried setting up your childViews in the ContainerView `didinsertElement` instead of the `init` method?